# Which subgroup of a symmetric group is isomorphic to the symmetry group of a platonic solid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, platonic-solids

Is there a way to directly determine to which subgroup a symmetric group is the symmetry group of a polyhedron isomorphic to? In example, I know that the symmetry group of a tetrahedron is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_4 \leq S_4$ or that the symmetric group of a square is isomorphic to another subgroup of $S_4$ with order $8$.

Is there a way to think about symmetry groups of platonic solids isomorphics without having to examine each one individually?

Comment: There is a unified method, see [here](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/geometry/Lectures/L10.html).